# Adding label at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, label

How do I create a label in Visual Studio, C#, at runtime? I've got this:

```
        Label test = new Label();
        test.Location = new Point(1,1);
        test.Text = "Working";
```

But it is not showing up. I've seen something like this used:

```
Controls.Add(test);
```

But I just get the error: `The name 'Controls' does not exist in the current context`

EDIT:

```
        public override void OnCollision()
    {
        Label test = new Label();
        test.Location = new Point(1,1);
        test.Text = "Working";
        test.Enabled = true;
        this.Controls.Add(test);
    }
```

The method is run when a button is clicked.

Comment: Where are you adding this label?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`Page.Controls.Add(test);`

in your code behind file. If that does not work, can you post more code from your aspx.cs file?

Comment: I'm new at this, so i don't know what you men by "code behind file".

Comment: And thats pretty much all the relevant code. The whole method is:

        public override void OnCollision()
        {
            Label test = new Label();
            test.Location = new Point(1,1);
            test.Text = "Working";
            test.Enabled = true;
            Page.Controls.Add(test);
        }
and it's called by the click of a button.

Comment: Do you have a file that ends in `aspx.cs` which is the code behind file for your aspx page? e.g. Default.aspx will have a Default.aspx.cs file which is where the C# code lives.

Comment: What kind of project is? Web application?

Comment: I don't seem to have such a file. Tried searching in the solotion.

Comment: Windows forms application

Comment: So it's windows forms application? Ahhh, right, I'm going to update your question with a new tag. We all thought you were talking about an ASP.NET problem.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are writting `Controls.Add(test);`

but I am almost sure that if you do `this.Controls.Add(test);` will solve your problem

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use `this` or not if you're already inside the class. Probably he's using it outside the class or something similar.

Comment: It doesn't, but i get a new error:
'Event.Text' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'Event.Text' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Though i have no idea what "Controls" is suppose to be, i've just seen it used when i googled the issue.

Comment: Added it in the first post

Comment: Ok, and `OnCollision` where is declared? in which class? anyway `Controls` refers to a form so be sure you are writing your code inside your form class.

Comment: method in class Text. My form is named Form1. I have a Text object in my Form1, which is a partial class. When a button is pressed, it runs OnCollision on my Text object.

Comment: have you tried Form1.Controls.Add(), the problem is that you dont say who is the owner of Controls Collection.

Comment: Controls Collection? I'm not following. The new error i get is: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Controls.get'"

Answer (score 0):

Update: Is it something like this you are looking for?

```
class labels
{
    public static void addLabel(Control ctrl)
    {
        Label test = new Label();
        test.Location = new Point(1, 1);
        test.Text = "Working";
        ctrl.Controls.Add(test);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labels.addLabel(this);
}
```

You can put the class part of the code in a class file. You need to add 'using System.Windows.Forms;' and 'using System.Drawing;'. You will then be able to use the addLabel method in other files in your project.

Comment: It does! Thats progress. But why wont it work when i call it from another class? What will need to be done?